# Modifying __getattr__ to return a nested attribute instead of the named object

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented

I'm writing an application with two basic class types:

1. DocumentObject
2. Property (of document object).

`Property` instances are attributes of the `DocumentObject` class and The `Property` class has several simple attributes of its own (value, unit, etc.) and some methods.

In trying to make the scripting as user friendly as possible, I would like
`objectName.propertyName`
to return the value attribute of the Property instance, not the Property instance itself. Of course, it is possible to write `objectName.propertyName.value` but most of the time, the user will be interacting with the value, not the Property instance.

It seems it should be possible to implement this behaviour using modified `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods in `DocumentObject` like in the following example:

**Input**

```
class Property():
    def __init__(self, name, value, unit='mm'):
        self._name = name
        self.value = value
        self._unit = unit
        self._isVisible = True

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def unit(self):
        return self._unit

    @property
    def isVisible(self):
        return self._isVisible

    @isVisible.setter
    def isVisible(self, value):
        self._isVisible = bool(value)


class DocumentObject():
    def __init__(self, properties):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'properties', dict())
        self.properties = properties
 
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if "properties" in vars(self):
            if name in self.properties:
                return self.properties[name].value
            else: raise AttributeError
        else: raise AttributeError
 
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.properties:
            self.properties[key].value = value
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
 

brick = DocumentObject({'length': Property('length',10), 'width': Property('width',5)})
print(brick.properties["length"].name)
print(brick.length)
```

**Output**

```
length
10
```

**Questions:**

1. Is is good practice to do this?
2. Are there likely to be some negative consequences of this decision?
3. Is there a more elegant solution that I have missed?

Comment: Is a property's unit intended to be constant?  For example, the length attributes name should always be the constant `"length"`; is the length attributes unit a fixed unit (such as `mm`), or can it be changed by the user (ie, `brick.property["length"].units = "feet"`)?

Comment: ```unit``` will probably be constant. But another attribute of Property would be ```isVisible``` which would be a boolean settable by the user. I would implement this using a @property descriptors for isVisible.

Comment: I've now implemented this change.

Comment: Good first question! It's fine that you've shown an implemented change, but keep in mind that we discourage editing your question once an answer appears.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear that in mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there likely to be some negative consequences of this decision?

Absolutely.

1. Calling `help(DocumentObject)` will not tell you what `Property` attributes exist in your class.
2. An IDE won't have any information for autocomplete.  Eg) Typing `brick.` and pressing the `<TAB>` key won't offer `length` and `width` as possible completions.
3. Callers can add, remove and change elements of `brick.properties`.

We can get around all of this by defining your own data descriptors.

## Reworked Code

### Data descriptor

First, let's create a data descriptor: a class with a `__get__` and `__set__` methods.  This will allow us to defined a `Property` on the the `DocumentObject` class, and control the way things are read from or written to instances of `DocumentObject` class instances through those properties.

The name, default value and units of the property can be stored in the property descriptor, since they are read-only values.

We'll also create a `Property.Instance` class to hold the data in an instance of the the property in the `DocumentObject`.  Instances of the `Property.Instance` will have the read-write attributes of `value`, and `visible`, as well as a link to the property descriptor for the read-only values.

`__slots__` is used to prevent additional fields from being set on a property.

```py
class Property:

    __slots__ = ('name', 'default', 'units', '__doc__',)

    def __init__(self, default, units, doc):
        self.default = default
        self.units = units
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        
        prop = instance._get_property(self.name)
        return prop.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        prop = instance._get_property(self.name)
        prop.value = value

    class Instance:

        __slots__ = ('value', '_visible', '_property')

        def __init__(self, prop):
            self._property = prop
            self.value = prop.default
            self._visible = True

        @property
        def name(self):
            return self._property.name

        @property
        def units(self):
            return self._property.units

        @property
        def visible(self):
            return self._visible

        @visible.setter
        def visible(self, value):
            self._visible = bool(value)

        def __repr__(self):
            return f"Prop[{self.name} {self.value} {self.units} {self.visible}]"
```

### Properties

For each `DocumentObject`, we'll want a container for all of the properties.  The `_get_property()` method we used, above, exacts a named property instance from the container.

Since we want this container to be a fixed size, with only the named properties defined on the class, we'll create a named tuple with those property instances.

To make life easy, we'll create the namedtuple of property instances automatically, when the subclass is defined.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

class Property:
    ...

class Properties:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls._property_list = [attr for attr in vars(cls).values()
                              if isinstance(attr, Property)]
        
        names = [prop.name for prop in cls._property_list]
        properties_type = namedtuple(cls.__name__ + "Properties", names)
        cls._properties_type = properties_type

    def __init__(self):
        property_list = self.__class__._property_list
        properties_type = self.__class__._properties_type
        properties = [Property.Instance(prop) for prop in property_list]
        self._properties = properties_type._make(properties)

    def _get_property(self, name):
        return getattr(self._properties, name)

    @property
    def properties(self):
        return self._properties
```

### Creating the DocumentObject

Deriving the `DocumentObject` from the `Properties` class will automatically call the `__init_subclass__` of the parent class.  At this point, it collects all of the `Property` descriptors, and constructs the `namedtuple` type for the property container.  During the actual `super().__init__()`, all of the property instances get created, and stored in an instance of the `namedtuple` type created for this purpose.

```py
...

class DocumentObject(Properties):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    length = Property(10, "mm", "length of brick, in mm")
    width = Property(5, "mm", "width of brick, in mm")


brick = DocumentObject()
print(brick.properties.length.name)
print(brick.length)
```

### Seatbelts

#### Autocompletion

Typing `brick.` and pressing TAB can autocomplete with `length` or `width` (or properties), because those are now named attributes of the `DocumentObject` class.

Typing `brick.properties.` and pressing TAB will also suggest `length` and `width` as autocompletions for the property container.

#### Immutability

The caller cannot add or change `brick.properties` because it is an immutable named tuple.

Of course, the property instances are not immutable, so the the following are all allowed:

- `brick.properties.length.visible = False`
- `brick.properties.length.value = 20`
- `brick.length = 30`

#### Help

Typing `help(DocumentObject)` now produces:

```
Help on class DocumentObject in module __main__:

class DocumentObject(Properties)
 |  ...
 |
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  length
 |      length of brick, in mm
 |  
 |  width
 |      width of brick, in mm
 |  
 |  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

- Do not write trivial getters/setters; this is not Java/C++/etc. It's more Pythonic to simply have everything public under most circumstances. Private-ness is not enforced anyway and is more of a suggestion.
- Consider using `@dataclass`
- You can drop empty parens after your class definition
- Under what circumstances would it be possible for `properties` to be missing from `DocumentObject`? I'm not sure why you check for this. Won't it always be in `vars`?
- Use type hints.
- Use snake_case, not camelCase for variables
- Do not allow arbitrary `__setattr__` on your `DocumentObject` other than to registered properties
- Do not accept a dict with redundant keys; just accept an iterable of properties
- IMO it's less surprising to have the document's actual `properties` dict override any request to a property named "properties" than the other way around

Suggested:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Union


@dataclass
class Property:
    name: str
    value: float  # ?? or maybe Any
    unit: str = 'mm'
    is_visible: bool = True


PropDict = Dict[str, Property]


class DocumentObject:
    def __init__(self, properties: Iterable[Property]):
        self.properties: PropDict = {p.name: p for p in properties}
        self.__setattr__ = self._setattr

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Union[PropDict, float]:
        if name == 'properties':
            return self.properties
        return self.properties[name].value

    def _setattr(self, key: str, value: float):
        self.properties[key].value = value


brick = DocumentObject((
    Property('length', 10),
    Property('width', 5),
))
print(brick.properties['length'].name)
print(brick.length)
brick.width = 7
print(brick.width)
```